# Updating using subquery that returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, sas

Need help. This problem blowed my mind.

My problems is almost the same as in the question  [Lookup values in one table and add to dataset according to IF condition (MERGE/SQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097549/lookup-values-in-one-table-and-add-to-dataset-according-to-if-condition-merge-s/9098920)

I am using one of the code from answers:

```
proc sql;
update master as a
    set loadport=(select loadport from lookup as b
    where a.LoadCountry=b.LoadCountry and a.LoadArea=b.LoadArea)
where lportmiss=1;
quit;
```

However I faced with error "Subquery evaluated to more than one row". As far as I find out it means that there are more than one loadports with equal loadports name in lookup dataset and sql does not know which one to choose.
My question is what refinements should be made to choose first met loadport in lookup dataset?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work.  You need to use a summary function to reduce to one row.  If you're confident one loadCountry/loadArea combination will always have only one port, this is safe; if you're not, then you need to think about how to do this properly (whether `max` or `min` is okay, or if you need to flag an error or something else if this happens).  Almost any summary function will do here.

```
proc sql;
update master as a
    set loadport=(select max(loadport) from lookup as b
    where a.LoadCountry=b.LoadCountry and a.LoadArea=b.LoadArea
    group by b.loadCountry,b.loadArea)
where lportmiss=1;
quit;
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that I had duplicates in my dataset and this helped me figure that out. Thanks!